# (LIST) If property matches replace object else add object

Tags: c#, .net, predicate

I am looking for a clean and efficient way to lookup if a certain object property matches a object property in a list. If true replace it, otherwise add it.

I know how to do this in several ways. My .NET way, first use `if (list.any(predicate))` then get the object and change it's properties or replace the whole object. This would be inefficient because i'm traversing the list two times.

Another possibility would be with manual loops. Just `foreach` loop the list and check it's properties, if it find a match replace it and break out. This would not be very `.NET` like and "clean".

I know plenty more but i'm not here for incorrect teachings. I would love to see how a `.NET` pro would solve this, probably in less then 3 lines.

Comment: Using a `foreach` loop seems very ".NET-like" to me. `Enumerable.Any` probably doesn't do anything different internally.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you may use something like this:

```
var element = list.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
if (element == null)
{
    //adding
}
else
{
    //change element properties
}
```

Comment: This way you have to lookup the element again in the list if you want to replace it or change its values.

Comment: @MennoGouw, no, simply change property of `element`, which you got in first line

Comment: If i change 'var element' the one in the list does not change right?

Comment: If you change `element` from first line, then this element from collection will be change. In first line you'll get link on element (not copy). This is true, if element is reference type, of course